# Specification, Standard, Protocol - what are the differences between them?

Tags: bluetooth, standards, protocols, specifications, zigbee

I wish to talk from perspective of computer science/electronic engineering. For example we have things like bluetooth, zigbee, TCP/IP, WiFi, GSM and much more that we use daily.

What is the difference in this case between Specification, Standard, Protocol? For example is WiFi a standard or a Protocol? Is GSM a Specification and so on...

Could you kindly clear this with some details?

Answer (score 2):

A specification defines those you should do in your implementation and it's more suggestive. I can't find a proper example in your field. But in programming, we can say a programming language has a language specification, e.g. C++ language specification, Java language specification, etc.

A protocol defines communication rules between two or more different systems. It defines events to drive the communication and actions taken when events received by any side.

I don't have a clear idea about `standard`, but think it may describe some more general concept than specification.

Your example, [WiFi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi) has nothing to do with specification or standard. However, there is some protocols associated with it, e.g. 802.11a/b/g, etc(from wikipedia, they are categorized as [802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) standards, which beyonds my knowledge).